# Enrhumer comme synonyme de doubler rapidement

Tags: vocabulaire, synonymes

Je suis sûr d'avoir entendu "enrhumer" comme synonyme de doubler rapidement chez des cyclistes. Genre:

> Comme il m'a enrhumé

pour dire:

> Il m'a doublé à toute vitesse

Mais je n'en trouve trace nulle part. Quelqu'un pourrait-il me confirmer que je ne suis pas fou ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

J'ai effectivement déjà entendu cette expression dans un peloton.

C'est une façon imagée  de dire qu'on a été doublé par quelqu'un qui roulait si vite que le courant d'air produit pourrait enrhumer celui qui est doublé.

Comment: Oui oui, c'est bien ça et je ne suis pas fou ! Merci !!! Bizarrement je n'ai trouvé aucune trace de ce sens au verbe enrhumer. Bon, faut dire qu'il y a des tonnes de pages sur comment soigner un rhume etc. Mais même sur CNRTL.

Comment: Accueil du TLFi : *la rédaction du TLF est terminée depuis 1994 et la plupart des contributeurs ont quitté le laboratoire. Il n’a pas vocation à être mis à jour. Cette ressource, qui ne fait pas l’objet d’une veille lexicographique, est donc close « en l’état ». Il est donc tout à fait naturel que les définitions qui s’y trouvent ne rendent pas compte des évolutions de la société.*